# Using filter on 'this' in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So this is my parent class

```
class ComponentStart extends Component {
    constructor()
    {   
        super();
        this.count = 0;
        this.state = {}; 
        this.repeats = []; 
    }   

    delete_this(index)
    {   
        console.log("I am deleting");
        console.log(index);
        this.repeats = this.repeats.filter( (item) => item != index );
        this.setState({ repeats: this.repeats }); 
    }  
    componentWillMount()
    {   
        for (let i = 0; i < this.props.number; i++)
        {   
            this.repeats.push(<StartMultiple key={this.count} id={this.count} delete_this={this.delete_this.bind(this)}/>);             
            this.count++;
        }       
        this.setState({ repeats: this.repeats});
    }

    componentHasMounted()
    {
    }

    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.repeats}

                <button onClick={this.add_repeat.bind(this, event)}>clickable</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

And this is the child class:

```
export default class StartMultiple extends Component {
    constructor()
    {   
        super();
        this.options = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
        this.temp_option = []; 
        this.delete_me = this.delete_me.bind(this);
        this.buttons = [<button key="0" onClick={this.delete_me}/>,<button key="1" onClick={this.delete_me}/>];
        this.state = { buttons: this.buttons };
    }   

    ComponentDidMount()
    {   
        $.ajax({
            url: "src/php/search.php?type=search",
            dataType: "json",
            success: (data) =>
            {   
                console.log(data);
            }   
        }); 
    }   

    delete_this(value)
    {
        console.log(value);
        this.props.delete_this(value);
        return;
    }

    render()
    {
        console.log(this.props);
        return(
            <div>
                <input id={"input" + this.props.id} type="text"/>
                <select>
                    {this.options.map(this.toOptions)}
                </select>
                <div>
                    I am some text
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.hide_info.bind(this)}>hide previous</button>
                    <button onClick={this.delete_this.bind(this, this)} ref={ (input) => { this.button = input; } } value={"hi"}>delete</button>
                </div>

                {this.buttons}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So what happens is that when I click the button in StartMultiple `<button onClick={this.delete_this.bind(this, this)} ref={ (input) => { this.button = input; } } value={"hi"}>delete</button>` it will trigger the parent's `delete_this` function (which it does).

So basically everything is working fine as I expect, except for the filtering part. I'm not sure why it's not filtering, even though it's correctly passing the component

Comment: There are many problems with this code in general.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing React elements that you create:

```
this.repeats.push(<StartMultiple ... delete_this={this.delete_this.bind(this)}/>);
```

to `index`, which will be `this`, which is the instance of `ComponentStart`

```
this.repeats = this.repeats.filter( (item) => item != index );
```

`this` isn't what you expect, but don't look up elements in an array by React instance checking. Remove items from an array with data only, such as comparing an ID or an index in the array.

Comment: but I'm passing the value from the child back up to the parent function? So wouldn't it pass the StartMultiple value instead? I'm not too familiar with react so I'm just using logic from vanilla javascript where I'd pass (for example) a button's 'this' to a function which would then remove via filter :\

Comment: A new `this` isn't created inside a for loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: I run a `console.log(index instanceof Start);` and it's false, however if i run `console.log(index instanceof StartMultiple);` it is true, meaning that it's functioning as I expect though...

Comment: oh, my mistake, sorry! I misread the first `bind()`