# How to filter through array of components/elements in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I can get the button through the event when it is clicked on. But when I do a filter, it does not remove the said button.

So I have my array in the constructor():

```
constructor()
{   
    super();
    this.options = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
    this.temp_option = []; 
    this.delete_me = this.delete_me.bind(this);
    this.buttons = [<button key="0" onClick={this.delete_me}/>,<button key="1" onClick={this.delete_me}/>];
    this.state = { buttons: this.buttons };
}
```

then I have the function:

```
delete_me(e)
{   
    console.log(e.target);
    this.buttons = this.buttons.filter((item) => item != e.target);
    console.log(this.buttons);
}
```

However `this.buttons` still has two elements in it.

I thought about another way to delete it and it was to use the 'key', but I can't seem to find anything about getting key value.

Comment: try this `this.delete_me.bind(this)`

Comment: You should be using state for this, so not this.buttons, but rather this.state.buttons via setState

Comment: @uzaif Ah forgot to mention I did it in the constructor. Will add it to clarify things.

Comment: @Chris I just wanted to test and see if buttons were being deleted first, which they aren't, so using setState wouldn't help at this point yet.

Comment: See my answer below, it should make more sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to bind `this` to the scope of your callback function. If you want to access the react object instance used to render the button from the [synthetic event](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html), you can do so using the private variable `_targetInst`.

```
class Buttons extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.delete_me = this.delete_me.bind(this);
        this.state = {
        buttons : [<button key="0" onClick={this.delete_me}>0</button>,<button key="1" onClick={this.delete_me}>1</button>]
    };
  }

  delete_me(e){
    const buttons = this.state.buttons.filter((button) => button != e._targetInst._currentElement);
    this.setState({ buttons });
  }   

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.buttons}</div>;
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Buttons />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

However, as [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/614112/chris) mentioned, your approach is not very much in line with the React patterns, and you should avoid accessing private methods or properties (usually named with an underscore)

Comment: I have a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435474/using-filter-on-this-in-reactjs?noredirect=1#comment70077039_41435474 but it's in regard to a component itself, which is passed. This time there is no event. Do you think you could have a look?

Answer (score 4):

The approach you are currently taking isn't really "react". You need to think more about a change in state rather than altering the dom directly.

One approach would be:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
      visibleButtons: [ 11, 22, 33, 44 ],
      buttons: {
        11: {
          label: "Foo",
        },
        22: {
          label: "Bar"
        },
        33: {
          label: "Cow",
        },
        44: {
          label: "Pig"
        },        
      },
    }
  }

  onDelete(deletedId) {
    this.setState({
       visibleButtons: this.state.visibleButtons.filter(id => id !== deletedId)
    });
  }

  render () {                                        
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.visibleButtons.map(buttonId => (
          <button key={buttonId} onClick={() => this.onDelete(buttonId)}>{this.state.buttons[buttonId].label}</button>
        )) }   
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

http://codepen.io/cjke/pen/RKwWwZ?editors=0010

---

**Edit**

An example showing adding and removing. The unique id is pretty primitive, and doesn't actively check for what is there, but you should get the gist:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onAdd = this.onAdd.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);

    this.state ={
      value: '',
      uniqueId: 100,
      visibleButtons: [ 11, 22, 33, 44 ],
      buttons: {
        11: {
          label: "Foo",
        },
        22: {
          label: "Bar"
        },
        33: {
          label: "Cow",
        },
        44: {
          label: "Pig"
        },        
      },
    }
  }

  onDelete(deletedId) {
    this.setState({
       visibleButtons: this.state.visibleButtons.filter(id => id !== deletedId)
    });
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  onAdd(e) {
    this.setState({
      uniqueId: this.state.uniqueId + 1,
      value: '',
      buttons: {
        ...this.state.buttons, 
        [this.state.uniqueId]: { 
          label: this.state.value,
        }
      },
      visibleButtons: [...this.state.visibleButtons, this.state.uniqueId],
    });
  }

  render () {                                        
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
        { this.state.visibleButtons.map(buttonId => (
          <button key={buttonId} onClick={() => this.onDelete(buttonId)}>{this.state.buttons[buttonId].label}</button>
        )) } 
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div>
          <input onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.value}/><button onClick={this.onAdd}>+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Interesting answer, however I am doing this dynamically. I also have another button which can 'grow' the number of classes in the array. I was thinking along the lines of the id, but is there a way to access the 'key' attribute instead?

Comment: This *is* dynamic. You can easily easily add to it simply by pushing into the button array state

Comment: kind of wanted to avoid having to resort to ids since imo, it can get clunky. I used this logic in Angular 2 fine, and was just hoping I could transfer it over (could remove just using the button's `this`). But if this is the only way in react, then I'll give it a shot first.

Comment: I'm not sure which bit is missing though? How do you identify within the array without some sort of unique id?

Comment: In vanilla js, I think if you pass the button's `this` as in the button itself, you can match it to an array or something. I might be wrong as it was over a month ago that I attempted Angular 2. However, I'll give it a shot and see how it works out first.

Comment: That kind of sounds more like jquery. Here is a super simple example of adding and removing. Type in the box and hit + to add, click a button to delete: http://codepen.io/cjke/pen/ggOapv?editors=0010

Comment: You're probably right on it being jquery... it can get quite confusing using all these libraries after a while lol. But I must mark Genaro Rocha's answer as the answer as it's more appropriate to the question. But your 'mapping' will probably help me in the future.

Comment: Thats cool. Be careful relying on internal properties such as _targetInst though. I don't mind which answer you accept but you should really try to embrace the react way when using react - it will make your life sooo much easier.

Comment: I'll try to keep the 'mapping' idea in mind and use it wherever appropriate.

Comment: Can I just ask why you use round brackets in your mapping? Is it just a person choice or is there an actual purpose?

Comment: In es6 if a function has only one statement, you can omit the return statement. So `const f = (a) => a + 2`. If that statement happens to occur over multiple lines, I use this form `const f = (a) => (a + 2)` as a) you can code collapse multiple lines, and b) the intention is clearer