# ReactJS: Remove item from list without ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue I can't seem to crack even after checking out a few other posts on here and trying a few things out. I am playing around with React and making a quick todo list. Easy enough as I can add new names and display them on the page as intended. I want to be able to delete items that I choose and for that I was looking around and saw others doing something like this to delete items:

```
deleteName(id, e) {
    const { names } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        names: names.filter(name => name.id !== id)
    });
}
```

That made sense to me but I wasn't adding any id's to my `<li>` items so I thought I could just do:

```
this.setState({
   names: names.filter(name => name !== name)
});
```

But this will just delete the whole list. What am I doing wrong? Should I restructure how I add names to the array to have an id and check that? I'll post the full component code below. Any help I can get is always appreciated. Thanks guys.

```
class ContactListPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.state = {
        names: []
      };

      this.addName = this.addName.bind(this);
      this.deleteName = this.deleteName.bind(this);
    }

  addName(name) {
    const { names } = this.state;

    if (name === '') {
        console.log('add a name first!')
    } else {
        this.setState({
          names: names.concat(name)
        });
    }
  }

  deleteName(id, e) {
    const { names } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        names: names.filter(name => name !== name)
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { names } = this.state;

    const named = names.map((name, i) => (
        <Card key={i} className='todo-list'>
            <CardText>
              <li>{name}    
                <FloatingActionButton className='fab-delete' mini onClick={this.deleteName}>
                           <i className="material-icons fab-icon-delete" style={{color: 'white'}}>-</i>
                        </FloatingActionButton>
              </li>
            </CardText>
        </Card>
    ));

    return (
        <div className='contact-list'>
          <div className="field-line">
            <NewName addName={this.addName} />
            <ul className='new-name'>
              {named}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with "Objects are not valid as a React child"?

Comment: Oh wow I apologize @OliverCharlesworth. I was getting that error when I tried to concat an array of objects to my names array. Ex: `names: names.concat([{ name: name }]).

Comment: Can you confirm the data type of `names`. Is it just an array of strings?

Comment: Maybe your question is similar to one I asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436251/how-to-filter-through-array-of-components-elements-in-reactjs

Comment: @fubar It is indeed just an array of strings. When I tried to add objects to the names array, that's when I get the error `Objects are not valid as a React child`. A. Lau thank you for that link! That looks like it could help me out here.

Comment: When adding objects to the array, did you change your `<li>` code to output a property of the object, rather than the entire object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell, but are you referencing `name` when the passed argument to your callback is actually called `id`?

Try this:

```
deleteName(name) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        names: prevState.names.filter(_name => name !== _name);
    }));
}
```

And change the following:

```
onClick={this.deleteName.bind(null, name)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this and nothing seems to happen. No deletions and no errors in console or anything. I think I just need to trash what I have and start all over again.

Comment: In your `deleteName` event handler, can you `console.log(arguments)` and post the output?

Comment: Ok so if I console.log both e and name from your code, I get this: e - `Proxy {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: ReactDOMComponent, isDefaultPrevented: function, isPropagationStopped: function, _dispatchListeners: function…}` and for name it gives me `undefinded`. So the undefined looks like my issue here.

Comment: You're not passing `name` to your click handler. See my edit.

Comment: Ok so now I can log the right name but it still deletes all the names!

Comment: Can you post what's logged from `console.log(arguments)` again? I want to check if it's the first or second argument provided to the function.

Comment: You got it. So if I add my name Dan and hit the delete button, for e I get `Dan` and for name I get `[object Object]`.

Comment: Awesome. Revised answer once more. Hopefully that should do it.

Comment: I owe you a beer my friend! You got it. I can't thank you enough. Question though. Is this an alright way to add and remove items from a list, or is it best to add objects and look for id's? Either way thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. There's nothing inherently wrong with it. You will run into problems when you have two items with the same name, so using an object with a unique ID would solve that.

Comment: Ah yes good point on the duplicate names. I'll look into adding objects to the array next. Thanks again, man. I just learned a few new things today.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing each name with itself, that will yield an empty list regardless of what's in it (except I guess NaN?).

`names.filter(name => name !== name)`

I think you want to pass the name into your delete function from the view. It's been a while since I've done React, but you could probably do this with a lambda in the JSX.

```
deleteName(nameToDelete) {
    const { names } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        names: names.filter(name => name !== nameToDelete)
    });
}

render() {
    // Simplified to focus on the onClick change
    return names.map(name => <Card>
        ...
        <FloatingActionButton onClick={(e) => this.deleteName(name)} ... />
        ...
    </Card>);
}
```

If you need to worry about duplicate names, then you can pass the current index into `deleteName()` rather than the string itself. Up to you if that's necessary or not.

Comment: With this when I load the page I get: `app.js:317 Uncaught Error: ContactListPage.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`. I'll look further into this response though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the callback for the filter, `name !== name` will always be false since an object is identical to itself. i.e `name === name`.  Therefore the expression `names.filter(name => name !== name)` will return an empty array and erase your results. You can change your `onClick` handler to something like this to pass in your id: `onClick={(e) => this.deleteName(i, e)}` and then use `names.filter((name, i) => i !== id)` to 'delete' the name, although I imagine you would would probably want to make a copy of the names array and then splice the corresponding name out of it.